# Replace with regexp i Template Toolkit

Tags: regex, perl, template-toolkit

I have this string (of jeans sizes): `W30L30 W31L32 W32L33`

And I would like to have `W30 31 32`

I am trying with

```
[% SET availableSizes = 'W30L30 W31L32 W32L33' %]
[% regexp = '(?<!^)W|L\d\d+' %]
[% SET availableSizes = availableSizes.replace(regexp , '') %]
```

But it gives me: `30 31 32`

Could you help please?

Comment: What is the rule here? This is just guessing, see https://regex101.com/r/Nff9J6/1

Comment: @ikegami, I see now what you mean. The code I posted actually is correct. Something with my data must be the reason then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what you claim, your code already produces the desired output.

```
$ tpage a.tt
W30 31 32
```

`tpage` is the command installed by Template-Toolkit. It's a simple program that processes the specified template using that library. Great for testing :)

---

`a.tt`:

```
[% SET availableSizes = 'W30L30 W31L32 W32L33' -%]
[% regexp = '(?<!^)W|L\d\d+' -%]
[% SET availableSizes = availableSizes.replace(regexp , '') -%]
[% availableSizes %]
```

I added `[% availableSizes %]` (because your template didn't actually output anything but line feeds) and some `-` (to remove the excessive line feeds).